# Can a Mac use AirPlay to stream to stereo HomePods?

Tags: mac, airplay, homepod

Set up two HomePods in a stereo configuration, and they act as one pair when used via Siri or an iOS device. Open the HBO, YouTube, or Music app on your phone, and *voilà*, stereo sound.

This doesn’t seem to be an option on a Mac. On my 2017 MacBook Pro, I can only choose one HomePod at a time as an audio out. I’m running macOS High Sierra 10.13.6. [Update: It’s the same on macOS 10.14 Mojave and 10.15 Catalina… Here's hoping for Big Sur.]

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Please edit your question to make it more about how to not why. Why Apple does or doesn't do or allow something is off topic.

Comment: edited, @JBis! :)

Comment: I’m on 10.13.6.

Comment: Hmm — as of macOS 10.13.6, iTunes can play to stereo HomePods, but the system generically can't, and other software (e.g. QuickTime) can’t.

Comment: As of 10.14.5, I can see the option in Sound preferences to have the output go to the "Living Room" (3 options, 1 for each homepod, and 1 for the room itself), but after selecting it, I always see a `Could not connect to "Living Room"` error.

Comment: @mattliu Did you try the same thing in macOS Catalina  10.15.0?

Comment: @mattliu Is "Living Room" also the name of an Apple TV? That might account for the third option. I do not see a "Bedroom" option despite having two HomePods paired as "Bedroom." I only see Left and Right. I’m on Mojave, as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** As of macOS Monterey 12.5, the native audio output switcher shows paired HomePods as one device, trivially allowing them to be used as stereo computer speakers.

[image: Screen shot of audio output UI in macOS Monterey showing a selected HomePod pair]

Answer (score 3):

There is an application that make possible to stream any source of sounds from mac to paired stereo HomePods. It also let you use others types of wifi or bluetooth speakers at the same time. I uses using it from some time ago and it works well, but is not free.

https://rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/mac/

Comment: Wow, Airfoil. I tried to use Airfoil a decade ago, back when it seemed glitchy -- although perhaps my 2009 wifi network or devices were to blame. Yep, great suggestion, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this workaround](https://www.macrumors.com/2020/11/18/mac-system-audio-stereo-paired-homepods/), but it's not working for me on a 2020 MacBook Air M1 (Big Sur).

The workaround is:

1. Play music from the Apple Music app on your MacBook
2. Select the HomePods as a stereo pair from within the Music App
3. Open the Audio and MIDI Setup app whilst the music is playing
4. Create a new Aggregate device, and select AirPlay as the output
5. Tell your mac's audio system output to play from the Aggregate Device instead of locally.

Didn't work for me (two stereo paired HomePod minis and a 20202 MacBook air running Big Sur v11.1).

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. The good news, if you haven't heard, is that no work-around at all is needed in macOS 12.5 Monterey

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you’re updated to Mojave as that is required.

Then follow these instructions:

> 1. Make sure that both HomePod speakers are in the same room in the Home app.
> 2. Open the Home app, double-click HomePod, then click Settings in the upper-right corner.
> 3. Scroll down and click Create Stereo Pair.
> 4. Choose a second HomePod to use as a stereo pair.
> 5. Click a HomePod on the right or left side to identify it. Click ￼ to swap them to the correct left and right channel.
> 6. Click Back, then click Done.

- https://support.apple.com/HT208807

￼

Comment: I already have a stereo pair — but it seems impossible to use the pair from a Mac, except via iTunes. E.g., how would I watch a movie on a Mac using Stereo HomePods?